Workflow for npm and ESM/EcmaScript modules in Visual Studio?
I am somewhat new to npm in Visual Studio - and looking for some best practice / step-by-step guide of maintaining a web project that needs to use ESM modules (minified) in a .NET Razor 8.0 project. I am using Visual Studio 2022.
I have a web project where I need to use several ESM modules, for example https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/ for file uploading.

From the VS terminal, I do this to install Uppy.
npm install @uppy/core

The npm package is downloaded and creates a bunch of files in the node_modules folder. Am I supposed to copy files manually from this folder to wwwroot/js/libs?


A colleague suggested to create a gulpfile.js that copies the relevant files from the node_modules folder to the wwwroot, but it seems to me with that approach you have pick individual files from node_modules, which makes maintenance tedious in the future.
node_modules structure for uppy:

I could of course just use a CDN (e.g. jsDelivr) to load the relevant modules but for Uppy that means loading a 515kb package. In this project, the modules need to be present on the local server.
What am I missing?
Can someone please give an example / guide on how to do this the most efficient way / best structure?

So your requirements are to minify and bundle a third party dependency from npm? Just pick a bundler and then define an entry that includes the module graph of your dependencies. Run the bundler and do what you want with the resulting output.

So can't really speak to how to do this in visual studio itself but this will just work out of the box without any extra configuration or work from within vs-code.... Your IDE is honestly of limited value when it comes to JS, if you make the switch to Typescript the typehints and type definition files can make it more useful but ultimately debugging for FE work happens in the browser/target client (use debugger keyword, and/or sources panel in "Dev tools" within browser).  Gulp is a pretty old option most folks reach for webpack as a "modern bundler" or ParcelJS for a lighter option.

Apologies for the late reply. I guess this is just to get the tooling/workflow right, and I am not sure I am doing that properly. Gulp is outdated, yes. I think webpack could be option if it can be combined with a CDN, fallback etc.
